# Changing input value while retaining original value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to do something that I don't necessarily think is the best practice from a UI standpoint(not by my choice) and change the value of the input after the user types it in.

The input field looks like this:

```
<td><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="number1" id="number1" class="currency"> / LUNA study</td>
```

and the JS to change it looks like this:

```
 var number1 = strToNumber($("#number1").val());
 var number1_calc  = number1 +(calc_value * 0.1);

     $("#number1").focusout(function(){
     $("#number1").val(formatCurrency(Math.round(number1_calc)));
     });
```

This portion of the code works how I want it to, the place I end up running into problems is when I need to use the calculated value for a different equation:

```
var number_total = number2 * number1_calc;
```

Right now I have the calculations setup to run on any change made in any input. So what ends up happening is after the focusout changes the value of the input, the next time the calculations are ran through it takes the new input value instead of the old.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX9XE/1/) of what im trying to do. As you can see the number_total  is updated on the change made to number_1 as soon as you enter something into number2, and this is what I want to stop.

Comment: how about a simplified js fiddle? looks to me like you should use jQuerys `change()` function

Comment: We could definitely use some more code here. As @Sionnach733 mentioned, you might want to use `$('#number1').on('change', function(){})` instead of `focusout()`

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle of my problem

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/hJ7jT/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question/scenario very well, but if you want to retain the originally entered value then you could use jQuery's .data() to associate that original value with the input element:

```
$('#number1').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).data('original-value', this.value);
});
```

Then, in your calculation function that runs on changes to any input, reference `$('#number1').data('original-value')` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm not sure if this will do the trick. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX9XE/1/) of the problem I'm experiencing. If you take a look you can see that it updates the total based on the changed number1 when I input something into number2, which I dont want it to do.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that calc_value should affect the display of number1, but should not affect the number_total?

Comment: Maybe, if you go through the form entering one at the time, you will see after entering calc_value and number1 the total_value displays the value I want. But then when you go to number2 and enter a value, total_value changes. This is because it is running through the change(function again and is recalculating number1_calc based on the changed number1 value.

Comment: Something like this is what I had in mind, using .data() to keep a hidden cache of the unmodified number1 value: http://jsfiddle.net/fX9XE/3/